# Successive sum of column only if another column has the good value in R

Tags: r, sum

I currently have a dataframe looking like that (with time in seconds and Zone1 a boolean):

```
Time Zone1
   1     0
   3     0
   4     1
   5     1
   6     1
   7     0
   9     1
   10    1
```

I'd like to have the sum of values for successive criteria so I would get something like this:

```
Time Zone1 TimeInZone
   1     0         NA
   3     0         NA
   4     1          2
   5     1          2
   6     1          2
   7     0         NA
   9     1          1
   10    1          1
```

So like this

I can't find what to do, how can I deal with that? 
Thanks.

EDITED: More accurate dataframe

Comment: So you want each row where Zone1 is true to have the length of the previous Zone1 run?

Comment: Yes it's that, but your code is working, I'll mark it as a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, where the last two rows came from, but here's my take on it:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(Value=c(3,4,1,1,2), Criteria=c(1,1,2,1,3))
# First, generate a logical vector that indicates if the criterium changed:
df[, changed:=c(TRUE, Criteria[-1] != Criteria[-length(Criteria)])]
# Then, calculate the cumulative sum to get an index:
df[, index:=cumsum(changed)]
# Calculate the sum for each level of index:
df[, Sum:=sum(Value), by=index]
# print everything:
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Value Criteria changed index Sum
1:     3        1    TRUE     1   7
2:     4        1   FALSE     1   7
3:     1        2    TRUE     2   1
4:     1        1    TRUE     3   1
5:     2        3    TRUE     4   2
```

To have the sum of the *last* block, use some data.table magic:

```
setkey(df, index)
nextblocksums <- df[index!=max(index), .(index=index+1,nextBlockSum=Sum)]
df[ nextblocksums , LastBlocksSum:=i.nextBlockSum]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working but it appears that my dataframe was a bit more complicated than just sum, in fact I need a time so I updated my first post. The time is the difference between last and first value in the range. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I managed to get it work by replacing sum by doing the difference between last and first line of a df[df$index == i]$Time in a For loop! Thanks!

Comment: That works, but it's slow for anything but tiny amounts of data. See my edit for a faster solution.

Comment: Hmm pretty complicated ahah, I've troubles understanding this and I'm getting NA in LastBlocksSum

Comment: Of course there's a NA in the first LastBlocksSum, because there's no previous block for that one :-) I've clarified the last step somewhat, just remember that with data.tables the first part (`df[i, j]`) can also be a join, try `df[ nextblocksums, ]` to see it in action.